# cPanel Apache and nginx on the same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I'm using cPanel Apache 2 on my VPS server to host PHP / MySQL websites on port 80.

So let's say we have myphp.com which just works fine.

Now I installed Ruby / Rails / Passenger with nginx (also with Ruby Entreprise Edition) which runs fine on port 3000. Let's say I have a new Ruby on Rails app and would like to host it on myruby.com and not myruby.com:3000.

How should I make this happen?

I configure a domain in nginx as follows:

```
server {
   listen 3000;
   server_name www.myruby.com;
   root /home/myruby/public; 
   passenger_enabled on;
}
```

If I change the port to 80 then it's not working (obviously conflicts with Apache). Please note that I do not add the myruby.com domain to the cPanel.

I have 2 dedicated IP addresses. I have heard somewhere that with 2 IPs you can solve this problem. But how do you instruct cPanel's Apache to only listen on a specific IP? Also, if I point a domain to my server how can I instruct the RoR domains to point to the RoR IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference who tries to run cPanel Apache and Ruby on Rails with nginx.

1) Configure nginx like this:

```
server {
    listen yourrubydomain.com:8001;
    server_name yourrubydomain.com;
    root /home/yourrubydomain/public; 
}
```

1) Just add the Add-on domain in cPanel
2) Log in to FTP, navigate to the WWW directory of the newly added domain
3) Create a .htaccess file with the following content:

RewriteRule ^ "http://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]

4) That's it!
5) At your second Ruby on Rails domain do not forget to try a different port than the first one. So for example, at mysecondrubydomain.com use port 8002, instead of 8001, both in the nginx and .htaccess configuration.

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

There you go, learn about mod_proxy and ProxyPass.

Comment: And what do you think of this solution?

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myruby.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myruby.com$
RewriteRule ^demo "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:3000%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]

Comment: Basically, you are proxying without using the mod_proxy module. Congrats, you win.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Apache to listen only on certain IPs in the httpd.conf file. Default is probably

```
Listen 80
```

Change it to

```
Listen XXX:80
```

Where XXX is the first IP you want apache to listen on.

You can then set up nginx to listen on the other IP

```
listen YYY:80
```

Alternatively, you could configure Apache to use mod_proxy to do a reverse proxy so that certain domains will forward to localhost:3000 and use the nginx server. But I think the above solution is better because it adds less complexity to the system.

Note that you might fight with cPanel on the change because it will tend to re-write that file when it is upgraded or you make changes to domains.